# Proper use of errors

Tags: exception, typescript

I'm using TypeScript for a reasonably large project, and am wondering what the standard is for the use of `Error`s. For example, say I hand an index out of bounds exception in Java:

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Would the equivalent statement in TypeScript be:

```
throw new Error("Index Out of Bounds");
```

What other ways could I accomplish this? What is the accepted standard?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

[Someone posted this link to the MDN in a comment, and I think it was very helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). It describes things like ErrorTypes very thoroughly.

> **EvalError** --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs regarding the global function eval().
>
> **InternalError**  --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when an internal error in the JavaScript engine is thrown. E.g.
>   "too much recursion".
>
> **RangeError** --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a numeric variable or parameter is outside of its valid
>   range.
>
> **ReferenceError** --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when de-referencing an invalid reference.
>
> **SyntaxError** --- Creates an instance representing a syntax error that occurs while parsing code in eval().
>
> **TypeError** --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.
>
> **URIError** --- Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when encodeURI() or decodeURI() are passed invalid parameters.

Comment: It seems to be missing a more general type for **invalid argument**. Not all invalid arguments fall under `RangeError`. Should you define custom types or just `throw new Error("<message>");`?

Comment: There are 7 subclasses here but `Eval`, `Internal`, `Syntax`, and `URI` are definitely not suitable for errors in code you write as a developer, and I'm not too sure about `Reference` (what's "de-referencing" in JS?). That leaves `Range` and `Type`, but there are limitless other categories of errors that could occur in your code.  `Range` answers the OP's specific question but it's the exception (sorry), not the rule.

Answer (score 77):

The convention for out of range in JavaScript is using `RangeError`. To check the type use if / else + `instanceof` starting at the most specific to the most generic

```
try {
    throw new RangeError();
}
catch (e){
    if (e instanceof RangeError){
        console.log('out of range');
    } else { 
        throw; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a general error? And/or where's the list of built in JS error classes?

Comment: There's a list of JavaScript error types and other information at Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: @basarat I think you should add `else { throw; }` here

Answer (score 55):

Simple solution to emit and show message by Exception.

```
try {
  throw new TypeError('Error message');
} catch (e) {
  console.log((<Error>e).message); // conversion to Error type
}
```

#### Caution

Above is not a solution if we don't know what kind of error can be emitted from the block. In such cases type guards should be used and proper handling for proper error should be done - take a look on @Moriarty answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to explicit type-conversion. Haven't found that info in the Typescript-Docs and learned something today.

Comment: do you know what is the purpose of adding <Error> is? e.message works fine for me.

Comment: @sbattou the only purpose of `<Error>` is telling the TS compiler that `e` here is of type `<Error>` so that you have (1) intellisense and (2) better type-checking. Be aware though that any cast does not translate to JS at all and is purely syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 50):

Don't forget about switch statements:

- Ensure handling with `default`.
- `instanceof` can match on superclass.
- ES6 `constructor` will match on the exact class.
- Easier to read.

```js
function handleError() {
    try {
        throw new RangeError();
    }
    catch (e) {
        switch (e.constructor) {
            case Error:      return console.log('generic');
            case RangeError: return console.log('range');
            default:         return console.log('unknown');
        }
    }
}

handleError();
```

Comment: This is great; seems more robust and cleaner than the other answers.