# TypeScript ensure all cases are handled for union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a union type that looks like this:

`type Action  = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';`

I want compiler to throw an error when someone extends it (by adding another type).

Have a look at this code:

```
type Action = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

function create(action: Action) {
    let something;
    switch (action) {
        case 'foo':
            something = action.toLowerCase();
            break;
        case 'bar':
            something = action.toUpperCase();
            break;
    }

    return something;
}
```

As you can see, the `baz` case is not handled in any way and it looks like it's totally fine for typescript. Do you have any idea how to force TS to throw an error here (because the `baz` type is not handled)?

playground: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQOQDNnLZQA%20OARgIYBORp2lAXtgFDO4CuqCK6cVEFYBAAUFbmgBcscagCUUAN7MoKqABsIwKAGdkAW00ALRKgDmy1doDuiYHENRRM%20UtVuocCtuh4C2CRbu7roGwMZmmFBiSGgAdMDIADLIVhBUAMJeIrIA3IFBqmT8FADWeQUeWeTU-vkVIUYmppHRPPHIAKpgkBlZwrl1BUUCZfkAvqxu-MDsVOgNYU15E0A)

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38633821/7143559

Comment: How would you define that rule? Under which circumstances should TS throw this error? And how many other Codes will this definition break? IMO. I don't think this is a reasonable expectation to a language.

Comment: I've no idea. Maybe something like `switch(action): Action`. I see that `const obj: Record<Action, string>`  works fine - you have to declare all 3 properties. So maybe I would go with this way. Basically I want to have an information from TS that some case needs to be handled somewhere in the code, when the dev extends the union type

Comment: But from the perspective of TS, it does not **need** to be handled. And instantiating Type with all its required properties is something different than *"I want this one specific function to handle all possible values of this one specific union type"*. Or do you want that every function that uses a union type **(in every TS code on the internet)** needs to handle all possible values of that union type? How would you define your rule on Language level? And how would you define for which functions and for which union types this rule should be applied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check that a switch block is exhaustive in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419170/how-do-i-check-that-a-switch-block-is-exhaustive-in-typescript)

Comment: @Thomas I really don't care which approach you take - switch/if statements/functions/objects. I just wanted some kind of a warning like "hey, you updated this array, 'now this code needs to handle this case'". What about this syntax: `switch(action): Action {}`? let's make it optional ;) Chill, I get that all code in web must be backward compatible and I don't want to break that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a **return type** for the function, TS will let you know that you're not handling a specific case as there's a possibility to return an **undefined** value due to the unhandled case.

For example, try in your playground the following:

```
type Action = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

function create(action: Action): string {
    let something;
    switch (action) {
        case 'foo':
            something = action.toLowerCase();
            break;
        case 'bar':
            something = action.toUpperCase();
            break;
    }

    return something;
}
```

You'll notice the following error in your return statement:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

Now, add a case to handle **baz** and the compile error will go away.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and I will go with this approach!